# wordpress get_categories example

Tags: wordpress

Based on the example on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories, I try to run get_categories function on wordpress. But the result show nothing. Is it because of the new version wordpress 3.0?

```
<?php 
$categories=  get_categories('child_of=10'); 
  foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $option = '<option value="/category/archives/'.$category->category_nicename.'">';
    $option .= $category->cat_name;
    $option .= ' ('.$category->category_count.')';
    $option .= '</option>';
echo $option;
}
?>
```

Need help on this one.

Thanks.

Comment: What does a `print_r($categories)` say?

Comment: var_dump message is "array(0) { }"

Comment: How about `get_categories()` without any parameters? Does that show anything?

Comment: And you *do* have categories that contain visible (published) posts?

Comment: Yes, it has plenty. I am using the same data on my local as the one on www.sepakpojok.com. From the parent categories "soccer" I am trying to get its subcategories.

Comment: Strange. No idea what this could be. I don't think that has changed in 3.0 though, not if it's in the codex like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using the same data on my local as the one on www.sepakpojok.com. From the parent categories "soccer" I am trying to get its subcategories

Are you sure that the category 'soccer' has the same ID on both servers (local and production)?

If you've manually added the categories on each, rather than copying the DB from one to the other, the ID's for the same cat could be different.

In other words, are you sure the 'soccer' category ID is **10**?

Comment: I have found the reason to the problem. Since I save the data through back door, I ignore wp_term_taxonomy of "count". After I update it, the function work.

Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to change it to this:

```
$categories = get_categories(array('hide_empty' => false, 'child_of' => 10));
```

Comment: I was missing `hide_empty`, once I added it everything worked. Thanks!